# Перезапуск экземпляров Firefox

Tags: python, firefox

Всем привет, моя проблема заключается в том, что при запуске скрипта открывается не нужный мне сайт, а страница с такой информацией: **This search session has expired. Please start a search session again**. Поискал в интернете, но ни к чему не пришел. Так вот, хотел узнать, возможно ли реализовать перезапуск экземпляров Firefox в скрипте? Большое спасибо!

Comment: Можно использовать Selenium с Firefox-движком. Или открывать firefox через subprocess и закрывать вручную

Comment: *при запуске скрипта открывается не нужный мне сайт, а страница с такой информацией: This search session has expired. Please start a search session again.* А не установлено ли в настройках Firefox что-то типа "Восстанавливать последнюю сессию при открытии"? если да - то поменяйте на статическую стартовую страницу.

Comment: @gil9red Я открываю Firefox через _driver = webdriver.Firefox()_ . Первый раз открывает вроде нормально, а все последующие с ошибкой